# Explicit form of the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am stuck by the following problem.

Let $ g = 1/y^2 (dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy)$ be a Riemannian metric on the half-plane $ S = \mathbb{R}^2_{y > 0}$. What is the explicit form of the exponential map $exp_p: T_p(S) \to S$ when $p$ is the point $(0,1)$?

Also, write down the inverse of $exp_p$, the geodesic normal coordinates, and the pullback $(exp_p)^* g $ of the metric.

I know the exponential map $exp_p(v) = \gamma_v(1)$, where $\gamma_v$ is the maximal geodesic with velocity $v$ at starting at $p$. In $S$, the geodesics are the vertical lines and the half-circles centered at the $x$-axis.

But how do I write down explicitly the exponential map?

Edit: I found the equation for the geodesics to be $L(t)=(a,be^t)$ (for the vertical lines) and $C(t) = (a \tanh t + b, \frac{a}{\cosh t})$ (for circles centered on the $x$-axis). For $L(t)$, to start at $(0,1)$ it must be $(0,e^t)$, from which its initial velocity is $0$. But I don't know how to rewrite $C(t)$ in such a way that it starts at $(0,1)$.

Comment: You know the general description of geodesics in the upper halfplane with this metric?

Comment: @Thomas the geodesics are the vertical lines and the semi-circles centered at the x-axis

Comment: If you know that you can write down the geodesics. At least a rather precise geometric description.

Comment: If you're willing to make use of hyperbolic geometry, what you're looking for is a conversion between polar coordinates on the hyperbolic plane and Poincaré half-plane coordinates. This is easily found by first converting polar coordinates to the Poincaré disk model, and then that to the Poincaré half-plane.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen thank you for your comment, but I haven't learned about hyperbolic geometry... I will definitely look into it when I have the time.

Comment: Schematic answer: given $v \in T_p S \simeq \Bbb R^2$, identify the unique geodesic locus (i.e. line/semicircle orthogonal to the x-axis) passing through $p$ tangent to $v$. Then find the point $q$ on this geodesic offset from $p$ by distance $\sqrt{ g(v,v)}$ (in the $v$ direction, as measured by $g$-arclength along the curve). If you can do all this generally then you will have an expression $v \mapsto q$ for the exponential map $\exp_p$.

Comment: Assuming that's correct, you just need to rearrange that expression to solve for v.